# NSInvalidArgumentException - attempt to insert nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I don't understand the problem in the following line of code.
I know that NSDictionary does not allow to insert nil objects so I am checking objects for nil before inserting them to NSDictionay, even after doing that crash appears.

```
-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    Request * logRequest =  [self.requestLogUtil newRequest];
            logRequest.requestParams = @{@"HTTP Method": ([request HTTPMethod] != nil ? [request HTTPMethod] : @""),
                                      @"HTTP Headers": ([request allHTTPHeaderFields] != nil ? [request allHTTPHeaderFields] : @""),
                                      @"Post Parameters": (request.HTTPBody != nil? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[request.HTTPBody bytes]]: @""),
                                      @"Query Parameters": ([request.URL query] != nil ? [request.URL query] : @"")
                                      };
}
```

It crashes with following reason, but not every time.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'

Comment: What's the value of `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[request.HTTPBody bytes]]`?

Comment: It is good practice to declare the variables first for a clearer code, like: NSString *postParameters = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[request.HTTPBody bytes]]; and also check for nil like this: @"Post Parameters": postParameters ? postParameters : @""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Adam Wright!

I got it. Its because of what you have doubted about.

Due to some reason stringWithUTF8String is returning NULL.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

I need to check for NULL as well for above method.